# How can I allow only friends to see a specific user field?

Tags: 7, entities, users

I want to make a simple social network website using Drupal 7. There will be a relationship type like 'friendship', based upon the [User Relationships](https://drupal.org/project/user_relationships) module.

After a lot of Googling, I haven't found any way to forbid non-friend people from viewing a specific field. For example, there could be a field containing the user's phone number. I would want other users not to be able to see this field unless they are the user's friend.

How do you do this? Are there any modules or anything else that could help me?

Comment: How did you implement the 'friendship' relationship?

Comment: using user relationships module

Comment: https://drupal.org/project/user_relationships